# Trouble Moving Photos to a Selected Folder Below API 29

Tags: android, file, camera, photo, mediastore

Does anyone know why I cannot move my photo? Saving the photo to the selected folder works fine with `MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH`, but how can I do it below API 29?
My code:

```kotlin
    private fun takePhoto() {

        val name = SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME, Locale.US).format(System.currentTimeMillis())

        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, PHOTO_TYPE)
            // MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH requires API level 29+
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "$appPicturesPath/$albumName")
            }
        }

        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
            requireContext().contentResolver,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            contentValues
        ).build()

        cameraController.takePicture(outputOptions,
            cameraExecutor,
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {

                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
                }

                override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                        val albumFolder = File(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "$appPicturesPath/$albumName"
                        )
                        if (!albumFolder.exists()) {
                            albumFolder.mkdirs() //works
                        }
                        val photo = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name)
                        val saved = photo.renameTo(File(albumFolder, name))
                        Log.d(TAG, "saved: $saved") // FALSE
                    }

                    val savedUri = output.savedUri
                    Log.d(TAG, "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri")

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        @Suppress("DEPRECATION") requireActivity().sendBroadcast(
                            Intent(android.hardware.Camera.ACTION_NEW_PICTURE, savedUri)
                        )
                    }

                    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        val action = CameraFragmentDirections.toPhotoFragment(output.savedUri.toString())
                        findNavController().safeNavigate(action)
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

I tried to move the photo using File.renameTo, but it always returns false.
My permissions:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

Comment: What sense does it make to use mkdirs for a directory that contains the picture taken,? And why do you want to move what,,,? There is no move code. The media store gives you a content scheme uri. You cannot use the File class for it. And why would you. Please explain your code.

Comment: You cannot rename a folder to a file name.

Comment: Attempt to create a folder to store the images:  
```albumFolder.mkdirs()```  

       Creating a File object representing the image file:  
```val photo = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name)```  

      Attempt to move the image file to the previously created album folder using the renameTo function:
```val saved = photo.renameTo(File(albumFolder, name))```

I'm trying to implement it this way because I couldn't find any alternative method besides ```MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH```.

Comment: You explained nothing yet. We still dont know why you want to move a file. You could create the file right away in the right location.

Comment: In my application, the user can create photo albums to later generate various kinds of videos. In this case, creating the photo file in the right place will be fine. Please suggest me how I could do this. But elsewhere in my application I would like to be able to add photos using Photo Picker ```registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { uri -> ... }```. How would I copy or move the photo selected in Photo Picker to the appropriate folder?

Comment: Do not come with two problems. Of course you can right away create a file in the right location as you are already creating a file in a location. Just change the location. Further i wonder what this all has to do with below 29. You are posting several problems. Post only one.

Comment: And for your last question: that is just copying a file. You did not tell which problem you have with copying a file.

Comment: I'm creating an image file in the correct folder using ```MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH```, but I dont know how to achieve this without using it because it requires API 29+.

Comment: Below 29 you use the .DATA column with full path.